# Seperate numbers and Letters & Rearrange the String: Variable Letters Has an Incorrect Value

Tags: regex, matlab, split, substring, strip

### Write the function **Separator** that:

Input: ***inString*** -- random string scalar mixed with numbers & letters

Tasks:

1. Seperate Numbers & Letters
2. Calculate Sum of Numbers
3. Count Number of Letters (*the white spaces counted*)

Output:

- ***numbers***,  string scalar of all numbers in ***inString*** with same order.
- ***letters***, string scalar of all letters in ***inString*** with same order, and white spaces Does Not removed.
- ***sumofNumbers***, double precision scalar of sum of all numbers in ***inString***.
- ***numberofLetters***, double precision scalar to count all letters in ***inString***, *white spaces counted.*

**Expected Result:**

- inString: "eng12in13e143e553rin154g 6p547ro548bl645em 8s65ol9v56ing"
- numbers: "12131435531546547548645865956"
- letters: "engineering problem solving"
- sumofNumbers: 131
- numberofLetters: 27

*Here's My Code:*

```
function [numbers, letters, sumofNumbers, numberofLetters]=Separator(inString)
%Insert your code here
   indexNum = regexp(char(inString), '[0-9]')
   numbers = []
   for i = 1:numel(indexNum)
       numbers = [numbers , inString{1}(indexNum(i))]
   end 
   % numbers 
   numbers = string(numbers)
   % sumofNumbers
   sumofNumbers = 0
   for i = 1:numel(indexNum)
       sumofNumbers = sumofNumbers + str2num(numbers{1}(i))
   end 
   
   words = split(inString)
   letters = []
   count = 0
   for i = 1:numel(words)
        indexLett = regexp(char(words(i)), '[a-z]')
        count = count + numel(indexLett)
        for j = 1:numel(indexLett)
            letters = [letters, words{i}(indexLett(j))]
        end
        letters = strcat(string(letters), " ")
        letters = char(letters)
   end
   % letters
   letters = strip(string(letters))
   comb = split(letters)
   letters = join(comb)
   % number of Literal Letters
   numofTrueLetters = count
   
   % numberofLetters
   numberofLetters = 0
   numberofLetters = strlength(letters)
end
```

The Code Returns Exactly As the Expected:

```
numbers = 
    "12131435531546547548645865956"
letters = 
    "engineering problem solving"
sumofNumbers =
   131
numberofLetters =
    27
```

However, the MATLAB Grader gives this Answer: **"Variable Letters Has an Incorrect Value"** and I was confused.

I would be very appreciated if someone could point out the mistake or the error, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got this!
I modified this line, before "[a-z]" and now is "[A-Za-z]" which checks all upper and lower cases for case-insensitivity.

```
indexLett = regexp(char(words(i)), '[A-Za-z]')
```

By this way, the indexLett would record all the indexes in the string that has alphabetic letters regardless of case-sensitive,

so for more inputs like

```
"Apple is good for health"
```

or

```
"A42pp3113le31 is 31g11oo456d fo442r h105ea422l44t2h"
```

could be counted as the capitalized words in the string.